# what is the use of copying a pointer, and then returning the first one

Tags: c, pointers

I have 3 questions regarding the following function. I marked them as comments in code.

1. Why do we copy char item pointed by `dest` (`malloc`ed memory) to `dPtr`, and then in the end (after processing the input string) `return dest`. Wouldn't it be simpler to operate on `dest`.
2. This function basically reverses the word only if it has dashes inside. Does the marked command `*subword = '\0';` put a `NUL` character at the place of previously incremented place (in `strncpy`) - `subword+1` or in the `subword`?
3. Is this function prone to some buffer overflows or other undesired behaviour? Now it doesn't give me any errors, but I think I just don't know how to debug it.

---

`len` is `strlen(word)`

```
char* function(char* word, int len)
{
    char* subword = NULL;
    char* dest;
    char* dPtr;
    size_t n;

    dest = malloc(len+1);
    if (dest == NULL) return NULL;

    dPtr = dest;               /* [1] */

    while((subword = strrchr(word, '-'))!= NULL) {

        n = len - (subword-word) - (dPtr-dest);
        if (n-1 > 0)
            strncpy(dPtr, subword+1, n-1);

        *subword = '\0';      /* [2] */
        dPtr += n-1;
        *dPtr = '-';
        dPtr++;
    }
    strncpy(dPtr, word, len - (dPtr-dest));
    dest[len] = '\0';
    return dest;              /* [1] */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `dPtr` is being used to move through the string and modify it. `dest` is being kept as the beginning of that modified string, eventually the return value of the function. At the end of each loop iteration, `dPtr` will point to the end of the modified string, and used for each successive `strncpy`. Ultimately the function returns a modified string, and `dest` is needed to keep track of it's beginning.
2. `subword` is being null terminated presumably so that only characters in `subword` will be copied into the result in the `strncpy` within the loop, but this actually isn't necessary with the use of `strncpy`. The function moves backwards through the string looking for dashes. For each hit, `subword` is the next dash-delimited substring. The substring is a piece of memory *inside* the original string, which isn't null-terminated. If you were using `strcpy` then you'd need null-termination of `subword`, but since you're using `strncpy` the null-terminators shouldn't be necessary: just be careful with your `n` values as the `strncpy` limit. This code null-terminates `subword` *in place*, i.e. by sticking null characters inside the original string argument. Which leads to #3:
3. As for undesired behavior, the function does it's work by modifying the original string argument - it's putting those null terminators for `subword` into the source string - even though it's keeping it's own buffer for the modified and returned string.

Finally, the code could do without `dPtr` by using `strncat` operations rather than `strncpy`.

Comment: About [3] - should I firstly `strdup` then?

Comment: @PeterKowalski actually, I don't think you need to: with careful use of the `n` values for `strncat` or `strncpy`, the functions will _stop_ when you specify, so you don't need to worry about null-termination of substring.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we copy char item pointed by dest (malloced memory) to dPtr, and then in the end (after processing the input string) return dest. Wouldn't it be simpler to operate on dest.

Because by the end of the function, `dPtr` would NOT point to the start of the `dest` string, so if that pointer was `dest` itself, we would NOT have returned the entire desination string we built.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you modify `dest` directly, the value returned by the function won't be the same. So you need to pass by a temporary pointer.
2. The `\0` character is put at the place of `*subword` (instead of the `-` character).